# How do you apply the pch parameter in R to individual points in a scatter plot?

Tags: r, plot

I am interested in changing the symbol used to represent the two most influential points in my scatter plot. In this case, they are rows 19 and 20 in the data frame. The code I have is as follows:

```
data1<-read.csv("data1.csv")

plot(h~w,data=data1,xlab="Weight",ylab="Height",
       main="Scatterplot of H vs W",pch=c(17,19)[data1[c(19,20),]])
```

Obviously, I cannot get this to work depsite several suggestions and hours of trying to figure this out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pch symbol is used for each data point and gets recyclyed to the length of the number of points you are plotting.

Consider this example

```
x <- 1:10 + rnorm(10)
y <- 1:10
plot( y ~ x )
```

The default is `pch = 1` and it gets recycled to be used for each point.
[image]

Contrast that with:

```
plot( y ~ x , pch = rep(c(1,2),each=5))
```

[image]

You get the first five points with one symbol and the next5 with another, and that is because you have made a vector of values for `pch` that specifies the plotting symbol for each of the 10 values being plotted:

```
 rep(c(1,2),each=5)
 #[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

In your case, all you need to do is

```
plot(h~w,data=data1,xlab="Weight",ylab="Height",
   main="Scatterplot of H vs W",pch=c(rep(1,times=18),17,19) )
```